# Session timeout configuration in Jhipster generated project

Tags: spring, session, spring-boot, jhipster

While configuring session timeout value in Jhipster generated project, I've added following to **application-*.yml** files:

```
server:
    session:
      timeout: 10
```

But session is not terminating after 10 seconds. Is there any other confguration point I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using token based authentication (Oauth2 or JWT)
then try changing **tokenValidityInSeconds** in **jhipsterProperties.java** file.

Comment: my application is session based.